# Docker /dev/mapper permission

Tags: docker, dockerfile

All new to docker, i'm trying to build an image of a software, during the
RUN apt-get install -y xxx command i'm encourtering issues :

```
Setting up lvm2 (2.02.95-8) ...
Setting up LVM Volume Groups...  /dev/mapper/control: open failed:Operation not permitted
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
No volume groups found
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Operation not permitted

Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
No volume groups found
```

what could cause this issue ?

my distrib is a Debian7, maybe should i try this on a more recent distros ?

here is the Dockerfile :

```
#installation d'hynesim
FROM debian:wheezy
RUN echo $(whoami)
RUN echo "exit 0" >  /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repository.hynesim.org/debian wheezy 2.2 backports' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb-src [arch=amd64] http://repository.hynesim.org/debian wheezy 2.2 backports' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN curl -o - https://repository.hynesim.org/debian/hynesim.asc | apt-key add - && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    hynesim-node \
    hynesim-glacier
```

Comment: So as far as I understand this is happening during the docker build process? Which user is performing the command in the dockerfile.

Comment: yes it's happenning during the build,
RUN echo $(whoami) returned me "root"

Comment: can you maybe post your dockerfile and show which apt-get install you're performing? (you can hide your personal fixtures in it) + tell on which OS you're running docker

Comment: i posted it  as an answer ! thanks for helping

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't use the kernel device mapper unless docker is running in privileged mode?

Comment: i tried to change the RUN apt-get install.. by CMD apt-get install, so the apt-get install were perform on the run and not on the build, running the image with --priviledged=true didn't solved the problem, maybe i'm doing it wrong

Comment: you shouldn't post follow-up info about your question as an answer. you have the option of editing your question...